# Javascript, finding object's parents in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object, lodash

I've got a Json file like this one:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "node",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "node",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "node",
            "nodes": []
          }
        ]
      },
```

I'd like to have a function where I pass object's "id" and I can get a list of all parent node "id" properties. I guess I'm asking about a recursive function that works one way to get to the desired "id" and then works back up the tree and pushes all the "id" values for every parent (how, I don't know). 
Is this possible in JavaScript / Lodash?

Comment: thanks for the answers folks, I've got it running using Lodash as per marvel308's exampel https://plnkr.co/edit/Qsm4sZigqZwYW7MRNuti?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do so in the following way

```js
let obj = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "node",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "node",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "node",
            "nodes": []
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
//console.log(obj);

function find(obj, id){
    if(obj.id == id){
        return [id];
    }
    let result = [];
    for(element of obj.nodes){
        //console.log('p', obj.id, 'c', element);
        result = result.concat(find(element, id));
    }
    //console.log(result);
    if(result.length > 0){
        result.push(obj.id);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(find(obj, 3));
```

Comment: thanks, that seem to work. what if I'd want to use an array of objects?

Comment: you see how I called the inner arrays using a for..of loop, you can simply call it the same way in the outside function

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I'm asking about a recursive function that works one way to get to the desired "id" and then works back up the tree and pushes all the "id" values for every parent (how, I don't know)

right. Quite complicated, don't you think?

why don't you mat that kind of stuff:

```js
var data = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "node",
  "nodes": [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "node",
    "nodes": [{
      "id": 3,
      "name": "node",
      "nodes": []
    }]
  }]
}

var nodesById = Object.create(null);
//quickly indexing the nodes, 
//and adding them a reference to their parentId
(function _(parentId, node){
  node.parentId = parentId;
  nodesById[node.id] = node;
  if(node.nodes)
    node.nodes.reduce(_, node.id);
    
  return parentId; //for the reduce()
})(null, data);

function getParent(node){
  return nodesById[node.parentId];
}
```

Now finding any node is a matter of a simple lookup in that map.